# In HighStocks, compare the values of the series against the previous value

Tags: javascript, highcharts, delta

In HighStock/HighChart 3.0+ is it possible to display the series y-axis as a representation of the change from the previous value. I know that you can use [`plotOptions.series.compare`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.compare) to represent the y-axis as the change from the first data point in the visible range.

So here is the result I am looking for - If I have following points on y-axis `[100, 115, 110, 105, 120]` then I want to see the following points to be plotted `[+15, -10, -5, +20]`.

Is this possible? I know I can just morph the original input to be the second array in the example here, but I was hoping to avoid this, since for the tooltip I need to preserve the first array.

Comment: Do you mean labels in a yAxis or points values ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Yes labels on y-axis. Just like we have for `plotOptions.series.compare` where only the labels are changed.